# Avoiding narrowing conversions with C++ type_traits

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a number of places in which I wish to use `std::enable_if` to allow certain templates only if a simple static cast from template type `A` to template type `B` (both of which are numeric) will not result in any loss of data.   However I am not sure what existing type traits, if any, I should use or if I should write my own.

For example, casting from `uint16_t` to `uint32_t`, from `float` to `double`, even from `int` to `double` is not going to lose any precision or negative sign.  But casting from `double` to `int`  or `int` to `uint32_t` would obviously be problematic.

I've monkeyed around a bit, testing `std::is_trivially_constructible`, `std::is_assignable`, `std::is_constructible`, etc etc. but I don't see one that will warn me if I try to go from `float` to `int`.

Am I missing something that's in the library currently or should I just write it myself?

(I already know how to write it.  It's simple.  Just want to make sure I don't reinvent the wheel).

Comment: could just treat warning as errors

Comment: Maybe checking list-initialization would be sufficient. It already prevents narrowing conversions. I do not know of any trait that checks for it, though. It should be easy to write that yourself.

Comment: Which C++ standard/compiler(s) do you use?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to make it an error, just trying to handle things differently when the conversion is narrowing vs not narrowing.  I'm supporting something that must build on several versions of Visual C++, all the way down to VS 2012, so my options are limited.  Fortunately I've already got a trait written, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something already in the library.

Comment: @dyp IIRC, narrowing conversions used to be ill-formed in SFINAE context, not sure if that was a defect in the language or in some compilers. Such a trait could be a little tricky to write.

Comment: @TemplateRex Interesting. I couldn't find a DR, though. gcc prior to 5 fails hard, for clang there doesn't seem to be an issue even for older versions like 3.1. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XrRnJuugZ4iej7CS

Comment: @dyp that example is not complete, because `double d { 0 };` is allowed whereas `int i { 0 }; double d { i };` isn't, see  [dcl.init.list]/7. Your trait does not capture that.

Comment: @TemplateRex Sure, but that is (as far as I understand it) not required for the OP either -- once you pass the constant expression as an argument into a function, the compile-time knowledge is gone. That is, any such trait can only select functions at compile time, such that they guarantee that no values in the source range are narrowed.

Answer (score 19):

## pre C++20 (SFINAE):

A possible solution leveraging SFINAE (C++17 required for [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)):

```
namespace detail
{
  template<typename From, typename To, typename = void>
  struct is_narrowing_conversion_impl : std::true_type {};

  template<typename From, typename To>
  struct is_narrowing_conversion_impl<From, To, std::void_t<decltype(To{std::declval<From>()})>> : std::false_type {};
}  // namespace detail

template<typename From, typename To>
struct is_narrowing_conversion : detail::is_narrowing_conversion_impl<From, To> {};
```

Narrowing conversion rules are implicity available with [brace initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). The compiler will report an error when a narrowing cast is required for initialization, e.g. `uint8_t{int(1337)}`.

The expression `decltype(To{std::declval<From>()})` in `is_narrowing_conversion_impl` is ill formed in case of a narrowing cast and will result in the correct value being set for `is_narrowing_conversion::value`:

```
// all following assertions hold:
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<std::int8_t, std::int16_t>::value);
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<std::uint8_t, std::int16_t>::value);
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<float, double>::value);
static_assert( is_narrowing_conversion<double, float>::value);
static_assert( is_narrowing_conversion<int, uint32_t>::value);
```

Tested with clang, gcc and msvc
Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6h9TcEcea)

## C++20 (Concepts):

As pointed out in the solution by rkoning, the same methodology as for the SFINAE based solution can be used with C++20 concepts, resulting in a more concise implementation:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept narrowing_conversion = !requires(From f) { To{f}; };
```

Of course the `static_assert`s still hold:

```
static_assert(!narrowing_conversion<std::int8_t, std::int16_t>);
static_assert(!narrowing_conversion<std::uint8_t, std::int16_t>);
static_assert(!narrowing_conversion<float, double>);
static_assert(narrowing_conversion<double, float>);
static_assert(narrowing_conversion<int, uint32_t>);
```

[Link to implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/vxY5z9nv6)

This allows for defining another concept `non_narrowing`

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept non_narrowing = !narrowing_conversion<From, To>;

// in case you don't need `narrowing_conversion`, `non_narrowing` may be directly implemented as follows:
// template <typename From, typename To>
// concept non_narrowing = requires(From f) { To{f}; };
```

Which then can be used to constrain function arguments, freeing us of the need to use `std::enable_if` (like initially suggested in the question):

```
void foo(const non_narrowing<std::uint32_t> auto);

void test()
{
    foo(std::uint8_t{});  // ok
    foo(std::uint16_t{}); // ok
    foo(std::uint32_t{}); // ok
    // foo(std::int32_t{}); // error
    // foo(float{}); // error
    // ...
}
```

[Link to example](https://godbolt.org/z/xxvxzKK7d)

Answer (score 16):

I am answering my own question this because someone asked me to post my trait and comments don't seem to have formatting.

```
template <class T, class F>
struct is_safe_numeric_conversion 
    : pred_base <( ( ( ( std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<F>::value ) || ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_floating_point<F>::value ) ) &&
                     sizeof(T) >= sizeof(F) ) ||
                     ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_integral<F>::value ) ) &&
                 ( ( std::is_signed<T>::value && std::is_signed<F>::value ) || ( std::is_unsigned<T>::value && std::is_unsigned<F>::value ) )>
{
};
```

Some notes about why I did what I did here:

- I ended up using sizeof to check the actual sizes of types instead of numeric_limits::max / lowest.  I don't like that and would have preferred to use numeric_limits but Visual C++ was giving me fits about that.  I'm wondering of perhaps it's because their constexpr implementation doesn't work in some of the versions I'm using.
- I use my own little "pred_base" just to make things less verbose.  I realize I could have used integral_constant for that
- Just today I realized that this disallows a valid conversion from a small unsigned type (say, uint8_t) to a large signed signed type (say int64_t) even though the latter can easily hold all possible values of the former.  I need to fix that but it's minor and at this point, I think I'm the only one still interested in this...

### FINAL VERSION (edited 3-FEB-2018)

StackOverflow tells me that someone just gave me points for this today.  So I guess people might actually be using it.  In that case, I suppose I should present my entire, current version which addresses the flaws I mentioned above.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this and I know C++14/17/etc allow me to do this far less verbosely but I was forced to make this work on VS versions all the way back to VS2012 so I couldn't take advantage of alias templates and the like.

Therefore I did this by writing some helper traits and then composed my final "is_safe_numeric_cast" trait from them.  I think it makes things more readable.

```
// pred_base selects the appropriate base type (true_type or false_type) to
// make defining our own predicates easier.

template<bool> struct pred_base : std::false_type {};
template<>     struct pred_base<true> : std::true_type {};

// same_decayed
// -------------
// Are the decayed versions of "T" and "O" the same basic type?
// Gets around the fact that std::is_same will treat, say "bool" and "bool&" as
// different types and using std::decay all over the place gets really verbose

template <class T, class O>
struct same_decayed 
    : pred_base <std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, typename std::decay<O>::type>::value>
{};


// is_numeric.  Is it a number?  i.e. true for floats and integrals but not bool

template<class T>
struct is_numeric
    : pred_base<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !same_decayed<bool, T>::value>
{
};


// both - less verbose way to determine if TWO types both meet a single predicate

template<class A, class B, template<typename> class PRED>
struct both
    : pred_base<PRED<A>::value && PRED<B>::value>
{
};

// Some simple typedefs of both (above) for common conditions

template<class A, class B> struct both_numeric  : both<A, B, is_numeric>                { };    // Are both A and B numeric        types?
template<class A, class B> struct both_floating : both<A, B, std::is_floating_point>    { };    // Are both A and B floating point types?
template<class A, class B> struct both_integral : both<A, B, std::is_integral>          { };    // Are both A and B integral       types
template<class A, class B> struct both_signed   : both<A, B, std::is_signed>            { };    // Are both A and B signed         types
template<class A, class B> struct both_unsigned : both<A, B, std::is_unsigned>          { };    // Are both A and B unsigned       types


// Returns true if both number types are signed or both are unsigned
template<class T, class F>
struct same_signage
    : pred_base<(both_signed<T, F>::value) || (both_unsigned<T, F>::value)>
{
};

// And here, finally is the trait I wanted in the first place:  is_safe_numeric_cast

template <class T, class F>
struct is_safe_numeric_cast 
    : pred_base <both_numeric<T, F>::value &&                                                                         // Obviously both src and dest must be numbers
                 ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value && ( std::is_integral<F>::value || sizeof(T) >= sizeof(F) ) ) ||  // Floating dest: src must be integral or smaller/equal float-type
                 ( ( both_integral<T, F>::value ) &&                                                                  // Integral dest: src must be integral and (smaller/equal+same signage) or (smaller+different signage)
                   ( sizeof(T) > sizeof(F) || ( sizeof(T) == sizeof(F) && same_signage<T, F>::value ) ) )>
{
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem and the answer given by @Quxflux helped greatly. Here is his approach of using the brace initialization rules adapted to a C++20 concept:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept is_narrowing_conversion = !requires(From from)
{
    To{from};
};
```

Usage:

```
// all following assertions hold:
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<std::int8_t, std::int16_t>);
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<std::uint8_t, std::int16_t>);
static_assert(!is_narrowing_conversion<float, double>);
static_assert( is_narrowing_conversion<double, float>);
static_assert( is_narrowing_conversion<int, uint32_t>);
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nTf8cqxeP)

Comment: Well that is a lot cooler than my overly-verbose trait.  I look forward to the days when we're all on C++ 33 and the C++ 20 days are a given ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the header `<limits>` gives you the primitives you'll need to build the full traits.

Here's a trait to check whether one integral would narrow when converted to another (of similar signed-ness):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<class IntFrom, class IntTo> static constexpr auto WouldNarrow = std::numeric_limits<IntFrom>::max() > std::numeric_limits<IntTo>::max();

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << WouldNarrow<int, short> << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already written my trait, I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something in the library already.

Comment: @Joe care to share your trait?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has mentioned it yet, a possible solution was provided by
[P0870 - A proposal for a type trait to detect narrowing conversions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0870r3.html#ch6.1), which has an exhaustive implementation.

In C++20, we can also easily check whether  an expression is valid and use this to define a `concept` or trait:

```cpp
template <typename From, typename To>
concept non_narrowing_convertible_to =
  std::convertible_to<From, To> && // (1) conversion is possible
  requires (From& f) { To{f}; };   // (2) this conversion isn't narrowing
```