# How can I use SFINAE to prevent narrowing in a template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, narrowing

I am trying to implement basic arithmetic operations for a Vector class and would like to support mixing underlying types while preventing narrowing from occurring.

```
template <typename T1,typename T2>
Vector<T1> operator+( Vector<T1> lhs, const Vector<T2>& rhs, std::enable_if< ! is_narrowing_conversion<T2,T1>::value >::type* = nullptr )
{ return lhs += rhs; }
```

I would like to implement is_narrowing_conversion so that it will only allow the conversion if the types do not narrow. Here are some examples:

```
Vector<double> a = Vector<double>() + Vector<float>(); //OK
Vector<float> a = Vector<float> + Vector<double>; //Fails to find the operator+ function
```

In the end I would like to write a second template operator+ function that will handle the inverse case by returning a Vector.

I found this post [with an incomplete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270158/avoiding-narrowing-conversions-with-c-type-traits). But it is insufficient as he notes that it disallows uint8_t to uint64_t conversions.

I also discovered [Daniel Krügler's paper on fixing is_constructible](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3047.html). Specifically in this paper he mentions using list-initialization which already has the narrowing semantics working but I'm not sure how to convert what he mentions into a proper trait that I can use for SFINAE template deduction.

Comment: I suppose I should note that I have updated post you linked to above as the "incomplete example" with a version that should now work even for uint8_t --> uint64_t and the like

Comment: The linked post now has numerous examples which correctly handle all these cases, and it has now become a valid answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using SFINAE through `std::common_type` ?

The following is a simplified example (no `Vector` but simples values; no `operator+()` but a `sum()` function) but I hope you can understand what I mean

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 sum (T1 t1,
        T2 const & t2,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
              T1,
              typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type
           >::value>::type * = nullptr)
 { return t1 += t2; }

int main()
 {
   float  a      = 1.1f;
   double b      = 2.2;
   long double c = 3.3;

   std::cout << sum(b, a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << sum(c, a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << sum(c, b) << std::endl;
   // std::cout << sum(a, b) << std::endl; compilation error
   // std::cout << sum(a, c) << std::endl; compilation error
   // std::cout << sum(b, c) << std::endl; compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I was looking for. I was able to implement both this function and the inverse (using `std::is_same<T2, typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>`) and have template deduction pick the proper implementation to use.
One thing to note is that with two sum functions calling `sum(b, b)` ends up with ambiguous overload resolution. Because T1 and T2 are the same type both templated functions pass the overload resolution. This is an acceptable limitation as I can easily use template specialization for the case where the type is the same, optimizing for each case.

Comment: Alternatively, I can implement the second function by doing `! std::is_same<T1, typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>` which avoids the ambiguous overload resolution without having to add a third template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Has some assumptions with respect to `Vector` but you should get the idea:

```
template <typename T1,typename T2>
Vector<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
    operator+(Vector<T1> const& lhs, Vector<T2> const& rhs)
{ 
    std::size_t const n = std::min(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    Vector<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> res(n);
    for(std::size_t i{}; i < n; ++i) res[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    return res; 
}

Vector<double> a = Vector<double>() + Vector<float>(); // OK
Vector<double> b = Vector<float>() + Vector<double>(); // OK
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I like that this solution would combine all of the varying operator+ functions I am planning on writing into one implementation making it easy to maintain the software. However, @max66 answered the question using SFINAE as was my original question so I accepted his answer.

Comment: No problem. I just think it would be surprising to have `a + b` work while `b + a` doesn't compile.  My solution behaves more "natural"/expected imo.

Comment: I agree, and I would prefer to use this solution to the template deduction approach. However the library I'm working with has been designed in an obscure way with Vector deriving from a templated class of the same type:
`template <typename T> class Policy`
`template <typename T, class B> class Vector : public B`
Which is invoked like this:
`Vector<float,Policy<float> >`
I haven't been able to use std::common_type to resolve both the type and the base class type in a single return. That is what is preventing me from using your solution. But that is a separate question from the one I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{}` constructor and let it detects [narrowing conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7) for you.
You can do that with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector {
    T value;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(Vector<T1>, const Vector<T2>& rhs)
-> decltype(T1{rhs.value}, Vector<T1>{})
{ return {}; }

int main() {
    auto a = Vector<double>{} + Vector<float>{};
    //auto b = Vector<float>{} + Vector<double>{};
    (void)a;
}
```

That is, you can use the usual form for sfinae'd expressions involving a trailing return type.
In case your `Vector` class template hasn't a default constructor, you can still work around it with `std::declval`:

```
-> decltype(T1{rhs.value}, std::declval<Vector<T1>>())
```

Note that, because of [[dcl.init.list]/7.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7.2) and the other bullets that follow, you can't simply do this in the code above:

```
-> decltype(T1{T2{}}, Vector<T1>{})
```

Otherwise, in your specific example, the following would be valid:

```
auto b = Vector<float>{} + Vector<double>{};
```

Therefore you must use the actual value provided along with `rhs` and (let me say) *test it* with the actual type used to specialize `lhs`.
As long as the contained value is accessible (either it is valid or the operator is a friend of your class) this shouldn't be a problem.

---

As a side note, you can't​ correctly define a `is_narrowing_conversion` that works properly in your case by using only the types `T1` and `T2`.
As an example, consider [[dcl.init.list]/7.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7.2) (emphasis mine) and the test code you proposed:

> [...] or from double to float, **except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly)** [...]

For you don't have actual values with which to make a test, all what you can do is trying something like `T1{T2{}}`. Anyway this wouldn't work. In other words, `float{double{}}` would be accepted without errors because of the bullet above mentioned.
Something similar applies to few other types.

---

Another valid approach is to use `std::common_type`.
Anyway, there is already a [pretty good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422686/4987285) that proposes it. It wouldn't worth repeating the example code once more.

Comment: I implemented the `{}` constructor approach and found that it correctly prevented the narrowing from occurring for my operator+. Then subsequently I added the inverse implementation using 'decltype(T2{lhs.value}, Vector<T2>{})` and realized that the overload resolution was ambiguous. In essence these two functions only differed by return type which doesn't amount to a different function signature.
It seems best for me to implement my operator+ in a single function using the `std::common_type` as suggested by all three answers instead of trying to do it with two separate template functions.

Comment: @MikeC. It doesn't make much sense to implement the _inverse function_. You can simply switch the parameters at the call point and you're achieving the same result.

Comment: That is true for the addition operator but not for others like division or subtraction, for non-commutative operators having both functions would be ideal.