# How do I force this template to only accept an integer of a matching type?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename integral_t, integral_t empty_Value>
struct IntegralHandle
{
     IntegralHandle(const integral_t value) : value(value) {} // Initialised with value     
     IntegralHandle() : value(empty_Value) {} // Not initialised, handle is empty
     
     bool isEmpty() { return value == empty_Value; } 


     private:
     integral_t value;
};

using OpenGL_texture_handle = IntegralHandle<std::uint32_t, 0>; // Zero is not a valid OpenGL texture value, so 0 can be empty

using My_Own_Integral_Handle = IntegralHandle<signed char, -129>; // This is obviously an error but I would like it caught because -129 is an int, not a signed char

// I want to be forced to do something more obviously wrong like

using My_Own_Integral_Handle = IntegralHandle<signed char, static_cast<signed char>(-129)>;
```

How can I make second argument be an integer, but be forced to match the type of the first argument?

Comment: The second argument already does match the type of the first.  From your comments, you may be asking how to ensure that the second argument is within a valid range?

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers why not just use an `empty` or `valid` flag?

Comment: @DrewDormann on most architectures, -129 is not a `signed char`, and cannot fit into a `signed char`.

Comment: I'm not sure there is something you can do here.  You can't stop `signed char ch = -129;` from compiling, which is basically what you are doing.

Comment: @DrewDormann But it's implicitly converted from an int to an signed char. I want to be forced to specifically cast it to a signed char for example. That way any underflow/overflow risk is probably lower. Or maybe it forces me to think whether the empty value can be a valid handle value.

Comment: @Zebrafish: I would probably make the second value `signed long long unchecked_empty_value`, and then add a `static const integral_t empty_Value` member, and some `static_assert`s that validate the range.

Comment: You could try taking the second argument as `auto` and then using `static_assert` to make sure the value fits in the intended type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Can non-type template parameters be `auto`? :O

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, since C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: @MooingDuck this paper was accepted.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah that sounds like a good idea. Use maybe std::numeric_limits::min and max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it with `std::numeric_limits` and a larger non-type parameter, something like this:

```
template <typename integral_t, auto empty_Value>
struct IntegralHandle
{
    static_assert(
        std::numeric_limits<integral_t>::min() <= empty_Value &&
        std::numeric_limits<integral_t>::max() >= empty_Value &&
        !(std::is_unsigned_v<integral_t> && empty_Value < 0),
        "value out of range");

    // . . .
};

using My_Own_Integral_Handle = IntegralHandle<signed char, -129>;

int main() {
    My_Own_Integral_Handle x; // error : value out of range
}
```

Note that this is a different question from [Avoiding narrowing conversions with C++ type_traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270158/avoiding-narrowing-conversions-with-c-type-traits) - that one checks whether type A can hold *any value* of type B, whereas here we just want to know if type A can hold *one specific value* of type B. For example, we don't care if `127` is an `int`, as long as it fits in a `char`.

Comment: How about if integral_t is unsigned long long and empty_Value is negative. I'm asking generally. I know that this is obviously the programmer's job of not making a dumb mistake like this, but is there any way of catching things like that? Is it even desirable for compilation to fail with a mistake like this?

Comment: Tweaked the answer to use `auto`, which sidesteps the various concerns

Comment: @Zebrafish:  if `integral_t` is `unsigned long long` and empty_Value is negative, then the `static_assert` should fire. It's generally desirable for compilation to fail, because the developer is forced to think about the error and make the _right_ fix.  Warnings or silent fixes risk doing the wrong thing without the developer's konwledge.

Comment: Oh, it might not fire because of the signed/unsigned mismatch. Ugh. Bounds checking is hard.  That would show up as a warning at least. Or we could add a second static assert that if empty_Value<0 then integral_t must be signed.

Comment: What about `IntegralHandle<int, 5.5>`?

Comment: A [type trait for avoiding narrowing conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36272533) might be more appropriate to solve this problem.