# Is there a generic way to get `size_type` from a C++ container?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, size-type

Is it possible to get a type alias for `size_type` from a container such as `std::vector` or `std::map` without supplying a `value_type` of some kind?

I am writing a program where I need the `size_type` from two different `map` types. If, however, I create a typedef for the first map type, the name `size_type` is not available for the second. My workaround (a.k.a., "kludge") solution, it to tell a lie.

```cpp
std::map<char, int> letters;
std::map<std::string, int> digraphs, trigraphs;

// This lie is good enough for both map types.
using size_type = typename std::map<int, int>::size_type;
```

In other cases, I would just prefer not to supply a `value_type`. Here is a contrived example.

```cpp
// Yes, I know this can be cleaned up by doing it in stages, but ugh!
using size_type = typename std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::size_type;
```

At the end of the day, we all know `size_type` is probably going to be an alias for `std::size_t`, even in corner cases such as `std::vector<bool>`. Nevertheless, I still try to do things the "correct" way, by using `size_type`.

So, is there a way to get `size_type` without supplying `value_type`?

Comment: No, not possible. And if you're going for full correctness, can you be sure that different instantiations will have the same `size_type`?

Comment: Yeah I've never really liked `size_type`. It's so verbose, and it's rare to see code that uses it consistently. I am one of those heathens who typically use `size_t` everywhere. Maybe I'm part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @HolyBlackCat. I guess I'll just keep on lying! Regarding instantiations, are you referring to the possible variations in `std::size_t` when targeting different platforms, e.g., x64 and x86?

Comment: No, I'm saying that what if `std::map<char, int>` and `std::map<std::string, int>` have a different `size_type`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with different platforms. `std::map<char, int>::size_type` could be different from `std::map<std::string, int>::size_type`.

Comment: The "correct" way, in my opinion, is using `std::size_t` and optionally using static_assert to make sure it works for whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and @Nelfeal: Is that common? Do any of the popular implementations (read: compilers) do that? BTW: thanks for the `static_assert` solution. I may switch to that.

Comment: I second that using `std::size_t` everywhere is correct enough.

Comment: Given how `std::size_t` is specified, it should be the "safe" choice. And I can tell you that countless real-world code bases rely on that assumption. You could add a whole lot of metaprogramming stuff to select the largest type from the two container types and static_assert conceivable unexpected scenarios, but you'll likely just be making life difficult for you and everyone who works with that code.

Comment: Just use `std::size_t`. It is always `std::size_t` anyway. Theoretical discussions about how it could be different are not useful.

Comment: @paddy There may be problems due to implicit narrowing conversions in member function arguments when using a larger type than `size_type`. For example in `std::vector::at`. But I agree that's an unlikely problem for practical purposes.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I don't know of any case of a standard library implementation doing that, but user code can add their own specializations of the containers for their own types and then there is a chance they use a different type (although even then the library writer hopefully has a very good reason not to use `std::size_t`).

Comment: The only generic way would be to use the type in question as a template parameter. That's rabbit hoel whre you end up with entirety of code written in templates.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I've never noticed different `size_type` aliases being different types, but also I've never cared to check. It is absolutely possible, though likely not common.

Comment: @paddy Or actually a better example with potential for vulnerabilities would be `std::vector::resize` if a larger type is used naively as argument. If it happens that `size_type` is smaller, then you potentially allocate too little after narrowing, causing a potentially-exploitable out-of-bounds access later. But still, that requires that somewhere `size_type` isn't defined as `std::size_t`.

Comment: Vaguely related: I remember wanting a `std::vector<T>` where `T` is that vector's `size_type` (for indexing back into it). It's obviously not strictly possible to define because it's a recursive definition, though you can use `std::size_t` and then assert that it's the correct type. I ended up just using `std::size_t` without bothering with a `static_assert`.

Comment: @Nelfeal: yeah, I've pretty much concluded that for the specific use case given in the original question, I'm going to add `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, decltype(letters)::size_type>);`, with a similar assertion for `digraphs`, etc., and then use `std::size_t` thereafter. And then I won't have to be a liar!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, is there a way to get size_type without supplying value_type?

No, because `size_type` can be a different type for every `value_type`.

Of course, as you said yourself, that's normally not the case and `size_type` is almost always just `std::size_t`, but both the standard library implementation itself, as well as user-defined specializations of the container templates, are allowed to define `size_type` differently for different `value_type` and there is no requirement that it must be related to `std::size_t`.

There isn't even any requirement that `size_type` must be smaller or larger than `std::size_t`. If you want to have generic library code that works with any standard-conforming implementation, you'll have to always consider `size_type` individually and make no assumptions about their relation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the help.

I have upvoted the answer given by @user17732522, and marked it as the accepted answer.

In addition, however, @Nelfeal gave the best answer for the specific use case in the original question. Instead of creating my own typedef for `size_type`, I should use `std::size_t`, and—if I am worried that a container might be using something else—add `static asserts` in the place where the `using` statement was before.

```cpp
std::map<char, int> letters;
std::map<std::string, int> digraphs, trigraphs;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, std::map<char, int>::size_type>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, std::map<std::string, int>::size_type>);

// From here forward, std::size_t is guaranteed to be the correct size.
// I can use it directly, or optionally, create a type alias that is not a lie.
using size_type = std::size_t;
```

Comment: Might also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270158/avoiding-narrowing-conversions-with-c-type-traits and related. Maybe you can "choose" optimal type to suit them all.