# Parameter pack which only contains types convertible to T

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++-concepts

Consider the following simple vector class:

```
#include <array>
#include <concepts>    

template<typename T, std::size_t D>
class vector
{
public:
    vector() = default;
    vector(std::convertible_to<T> auto const&... x) requires (sizeof...(x) == D)
        : m_x({ static_cast<T>(x)... })
    {}
    
private:
    std::array<T, D> m_x;
};
```

The idea is that the ctor should only be applicable if all `x`'s are convertible (or would it be better to require them to be *constructible*?) to type `T`. However, the following code compiles without an error:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int, 3> x{ 1., 2, 3 };
    return 0;
}
```

So, what am I understanding wrong here? The first `x` is `1.` which is of type `double` and should not be *implicitly* convertible to `int`. It is *explicitly* convertible to `int` though. Maybe that's wrong here. But how should I alter the code then? `convertible_from` also does not produce a compiler error.

[Here is the code.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa094486c98c463e)

Comment: `double` is implicitly convertible to `int`.

Comment: @Barry Yes, sorry, you are right. But I think it is clear what I'm after here. If we convert a double to int, we data loss is possible either when `std::numeric::limits<double>::max()` is larger than `std::numeric::limits<int>::max()` or when the double actually has a nontrivial fractional part. I would like that the ctor is not applicable in that case, but I don't know how I should alter the requirement.

Comment: What about [doing](https://godbolt.org/z/P5anx1ocM) `sizeof...(x) == D && requires { (T{x}, ...); }` ?

Comment: You would need something like this: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0870r3.html#ch6.1

Answer (score 0):

`double` is implicitly convertible to `int`, so `std::convertible_to<double, int>` is true.
You're essentially asking for a "losslessly convertible to" trait, and there are two approaches that.

In short, a definition in terms of narrowing conversions is very restrictive and doesn't even allow `char -> long double`. A definition in terms of conversion rank is more flexible, but *technically* allows some precision loss.

#### Definition in terms of non-narrowing

One way to formalize "lossless" is to equate it with non-narrowing. List initialization does not allow for narrowing conversions, so we can define a concept based on that:

```cpp
template <typename From, typename To>
concept non_narrowing_convertible_to =
  std::convertible_to<From, To> && // (1) conversion is possible
  requires (From& f) { To{f}; };   // (2) this conversion isn't narrowing

static_assert(!non_narrowing_convertible_to<double, int>);  // passes
static_assert(!non_narrowing_convertible_to<int, double>);  // passes
static_assert(non_narrowing_convertible_to<float, double>); // passes
```

However, `int -> double` is considered narrowing, and that might not be what you want.

---

*Note: Commenter @Osyotr has linked [P0870 - A proposal for a type trait to detect narrowing conversions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0870r3.html#ch6.1) which could be used prior to C++20 too. See also [Avoiding narrowing conversions with C++ type_traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36270158/5740428.)*

#### Definition in terms of conversion rank

Another way to approach this is through conversion rank. The conversion from `int` to `double` is narrowing, but may be acceptable on the basis that `double` has a greater conversion rank. We can create a concept based on this as well:

```cpp
template <typename From, typename To>
concept rank_increase_convertible_to =
  std::convertible_to<From, To>                   && // (1) conversion is possible
  std::same_as<To, std::common_type_t<From, To>>;    // (2) this conversion keeps
                                                     //     or increases rank

static_assert(!rank_increase_convertible_to<double, int>);  // passes
static_assert(rank_increase_convertible_to<int, double>);   // passes
static_assert(rank_increase_convertible_to<float, double>); // passes
```

#### Applying the concept to your code

You can then replace `std::convertible_to<T>` with `non_narrowing_convertible_to<T>` or `rank_increase_convertible_to<T>` in your code.