std::invocable without narrowing conversions and slicing
I want a concept for a callable that avoids narrowing conversions and slicing. On the very first attempt to write it, I've found out that a naïve use of std::invocable<T> rejects callables that were OK in duck typed templates.
The following code prints everything when concepts are commented out:
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>
#include <print>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct ValueHolder {
    using ValueType = T;

    T value;
};

template <typename From, typename To>
concept non_narrowing = requires(From f) { To{f}; };

template<
    typename Value,
    typename T = std::remove_reference_t<Value>::ValueType,
    // typename Arg,
    typename Callable
>
/*
requires
    // Fails to accept callables valid in a duck typed template.
    std::invocable<Callable, T>

    // Compiles, but doesn't actually constrain the Arg.
    // Duplicates code from the function itself.
    requires (Value&& val, Callable&& callable) {
        std::forward<Callable>(callable)(std::forward<Value>(val).value);
    }

    // Doesn't compile: can't deduce Arg.
    // non_narrowing<T, Arg>
    //     && std::invocable<Callable, Arg>

    // Doesn't compile: can't deduce Arg.
    // Duplicates code from the function itself.
    // requires (Value&& val, Callable&& callable) {
    //     std::forward<Callable>(callable)(non_narrowing<decltype(std::forward<Value>(val).value), Arg>);
    // }
*/
auto callOnValue(Value&& val, Callable&& callable)
{
    std::forward<Callable>(callable)(std::forward<Value>(val).value);
}

void printI32(std::int32_t) { std::println("i32"); }
void printI32Ref(std::int32_t&) { std::println("i32&"); }
void printI32RefRef(std::int32_t&&) { std::println("i32&&"); }
void printConstI32Ref(const std::int32_t &) { std::println("const i32&"); }

void printI16(std::int16_t) { std::println("i16"); }
void printI64(std::int64_t) { std::println("i64"); }

struct Base {};
struct Derived: public Base {};

void printBase(Base) { std::println("Base"); }
void printConstBaseRef(const Base&) { std::println("const Base&"); }
void printDerived(Derived) { std::println("Derived"); }
void printConstDerivedRef(const Derived&) { std::println("const Derived&"); }

int main()
{
    ValueHolder i{static_cast<std::int32_t>(42)};
    callOnValue(i, printI32);
    callOnValue(i, printI32Ref);

    callOnValue(ValueHolder{static_cast<std::int32_t>(42)}, printI32RefRef);

    const auto ci{i};
    callOnValue(ci, printI32);
    callOnValue(ci, printConstI32Ref);

    callOnValue(i, printI16);
    callOnValue(i, printI64);

    ValueHolder d{Derived{}};
    callOnValue(d, printBase);
    callOnValue(d, printConstBaseRef);
    callOnValue(d, printDerived);
    callOnValue(d, printConstDerivedRef);
}

Uncommenting
requires
    std::invocable<Callable, T>

makes it impossible to call printIntRef.
Uncommenting
requires (Value&& val, Callable&& callable) {
    std::forward<Callable>(callable)(std::forward<Value>(val).value);
}

compiles, but doesn't actually constrain the callable, and looks like writing the function body twice.
Uncommenting typename Arg and either
std::non_narrowing<T, Arg>
    && std::invocable<Callable, Arg>

or
requires (Value&& val, Callable&& callable) {
     std::forward<Callable>(callable)(non_narrowing<decltype(std::forward<Value>(val).value), Arg>);
}

leads to Arg could not be deduced.
How does one write a concept LosslessInvocable<PassByWhateverWorksInDuckTypedTemplates<T>> that:

Allows all default pass-bys to be reproduced (i.e. callable accepting pass by value, by const ref, by ref for lvalues, and by ref-ref for rvalues).
Prevents narrowing conversions: printI16 in the above does not compile, but printI64 does.
Accepts contravariant callables, i.e. a callable accepting Base& or Base* can be called on a ValueHolder<Derived>.
Prevents slicing: a pass by value callable accepting Base doesn't compile for ValueHolder<Derived>.


The problem is a very old rule in C++:
r-values cannot bind to none-const lvalue references. So std::invocable<R(T&),T> evaluates to false if std::is_lvalue_refernce_v<T> is false.
But std::invocable<R(T const&),T> always evaluates to true, because const lvalue reference can bind to (almost)any object with same basic type.

One question by question.

The problem is that you are confused about what you actually want to do.
First, the callOnValue should be like
void callOnValue(Value&& val, Callable&& callable)
{
    std::forward<Callable>(callable)(std::forward_like<Value>(val.value));
}

Otherwise, you get issues with the proper forwarding of the member value.
The std::forward_like is from C++23, so you can use a substitute implementation:
template<class T, class U>
constexpr auto&& forward_like(U&& x) noexcept
{
    constexpr bool is_adding_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>)
    {
        if constexpr (is_adding_const)
            return std::as_const(x);
        else
            return static_cast<U&>(x);
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr (is_adding_const)
            return std::move(std::as_const(x));
        else
            return std::move(x);
    }
}

The second issue is that Value in the template might be constant, so to refer to ValueType of Value you'd better write.
typename T = std::remove_cvref_t<Value>::ValueType

The third issue is how to test whether you can perform the call correctly. How to do that? You need to copy traits of Value to T and test invocability on the result. You can do it via a custom type-trait:
template<class T, class U>
struct copy_traits
{
    using type = decltype(forward_like<T>(std::declval<U>()));
};

template<class T, class U>
using copy_traits_t = typename copy_traits<T,U>::type; 

where forward_like is as above, and test invocability it by std::invocable<Callable, copy_traits_t<Value, T> >
You get code like this:
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct ValueHolder {
    using ValueType = T;

    T value;
};

template<class T, class U>
constexpr auto&& forward_like(U&& x) noexcept
{
    constexpr bool is_adding_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>)
    {
        if constexpr (is_adding_const)
            return std::as_const(x);
        else
            return static_cast<U&>(x);
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr (is_adding_const)
            return std::move(std::as_const(x));
        else
            return std::move(x);
    }
}

template<class T, class U>
struct copy_traits
{
    using type = decltype(forward_like<T>(std::declval<U>()));
};

template<class T, class U>
using copy_traits_t = typename copy_traits<T,U>::type;

template<
    typename Value,
    typename Callable,
    typename T = std::remove_cvref_t<Value>::ValueType
>
requires (std::invocable<Callable, copy_traits_t<Value, T> >)
void callOnValue(Value&& val, Callable&& callable)
{
    std::forward<Callable>(callable)(forward_like<Value>(val.value));
}

void printI32(std::int32_t) { std::cout << "i32\n"; }
void printI32Ref(std::int32_t&) { std::cout << "i32&\n"; }
void printI32RefRef(std::int32_t&&) {std::cout << "i32&&\n"; }
void printConstI32Ref(const std::int32_t &) {std::cout << "const i32&\n"; }

void printI16(std::int16_t) { std::cout << "i16\n"; }
void printI64(std::int64_t) { std::cout << "i16\n"; }

int main()
{
    ValueHolder i{static_cast<std::int32_t>(42)};
    callOnValue(i, printI32);
    callOnValue(i, printI32Ref);

    callOnValue(ValueHolder{static_cast<std::int32_t>(42)}, printI32RefRef);
    const auto ci{i};
    callOnValue(ci, printI32);
    callOnValue(ci, printConstI32Ref);

    callOnValue(i, printI16);
    callOnValue(i, printI64);
}

Alternatively, you could've just written a custom concept:
requires (requires (Value&& val, Callable&& callable)
{
      {std::forward<Callable>(callable)(forward_like<Value>(val.value))};
})


If someone disagrees they should at least write what they are unhappy about

That's not the proper use of forward_like. The OP use of forward is more generic and idiomatic. If Value is of reference type(corner case) forward_like results in UB. Applying a data member of none-reference type on an rvalue results in an rvalue reference to data member; but if the member is of reference type, it won't be affected. forward_like discards the reference qualifiers and forces the requested ref Q on the member.

@Red.Wave The class type name is ValueHolder. OP has no intention to write any kind of ValueHolder<int&> or ValueHolder<const int> nor was it tested by OP. So, it is irrelevant to the question.

If the the member is indeed of value type, forward_like does not add any advantage. Thus the core of your answer becomes irrelevant to OP.

@Red.Wave the core of the answer is about what he actually wants to test - copy traits.

@Red.Wave also; I don't agree with you about the improper usage of forward_like - it properly merges traits of T into U, so there's no UB even if he used int& or int const for value.

What if the object is rvalue, holding an lvalue reference? Moving from an lvalue creates UB. Nevertheless forward_like is irrelevant to the OP.

@Red.Wave It converts lvalue reference to rvalue reference, and I don't see how that would be an issue here. "Moving from an lvalue creates UB" This is nonsense. It could create UB if the object were misused afterwards, but since he already forwarded it as rvalue that's up to the user to figure out what he intended by the operation.

@Red.Wave thank you for your comment, but it's dubious in quality or relevance to the question or answer.

Moved-from objects must generally not be used before reassigned. This extra post condition is often overlooked, resulting in UB. Try with a std::unique_ptr, and witness the crash.

@Red.Wave Well, yes, but given that the potential reference was forwarded via move - I assume that's the user's intention. I am not going to perform a copy if the user intends to perform a move.

@Red.Wave Say, the user has ValueHolder<std::vector<int>&> val, then to forward internal value via lvalue reference user needs to write callOn(val), to call on rvalue reference the needs to write callOn(std::move(val)). But if I don't use forward_like, the user cannot actually perform the move, and it will ignore the user's intent. Your position ignores common sense.

I have made it clear. If you use forward_like on a reference member, the overall outcome has a high chance of UB. There's no point in further arguments. Apply forward on the top-level object then access the member, just like the OP; it gives the correct type. There are certain cases where forward_like is the proper tool, but those are nuch more complicated, and irrelevant to OP.

@Red.Wave In OP's case, there's 0 chance of UB. And in the extended scenario, it is a question of what the user's intent is, which you ignore entirely and have provided zero arguments on. Next, say that users shouldn't use forwarding as it may result in a move and cause UB. This is a nonsense argument.

‘The problem is that you are confused about what you actually want to do.’: I wanted to constrain the callable to avoid narrowing conversions and slicing (see points 2–4 in the question). Then I found out that a naïve use of std::invocable<T> rejects callables that were OK in duck typed templates. So I asked the question about a concept that doesn't reject callables that were OK in duck typed templates while still rejecting narrowing conversions and slicing, let's say a LosslessCallable<PassByWhateverWorksInDuckTypeTemplates<T>>. Probably I should rewrite the question.

‘ValueHolder<const int> nor was it tested by OP’: I do test on a const copy const auto ci{i};. There is no callOnValue(ci, printI32Ref); because it obviously doesn't compile.

@NilAdmirari In this case, write the custom concept like it is written at the bottom - just plug in whatever expression. With std::invocable, you must be accurate about constness and reference type for it to work, as function that accepts lvalue reference wouldn't accept a temporary.

@NilAdmirari you have const ValueHolder<int> not ValueHolder<const int>. And the code I provided perfectly suits ValueHolder<const int> as well.

Edited the question to make it more clear (maybe). ‘write the custom concept like it is written at the bottom’: how am I supposed to do that? Introducing callable's Arg and attempting to constrain it with non_narrowing<T, Arg> doesn't compile.

@NilAdmirari You should've separated this into multiple questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632236/how-is-possible-to-deduce-function-argument-type-in-c for deducing arguments, but it doesn't work except for trivial cases. Generally, it's not recommended.

@NilAdmirari There is no general trait for non_narrowing, and I don't see how it can be done in general. You can write a type trait that tests integers and floats based on size, sign, etc.

‘deducing arguments, but it doesn't work except for trivial cases’: too bad. It means that the concept in question is not implementable. ‘There is no general trait for non_narrowing’: actually there is one https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603594/19055149, I've even copied it into the question.

@NilAdmirari it is not a general trait. Imagine you have a class that's constructed implicitly from char but you call the function with int - you get a narrowing conversation - the trait will not he able to tell that, as it is specialised only to basic arithmetic types.

@NilAdmirari identifying call argument is possible only when input is a function or a unique operator (). When it is a template or multiple operator - there's no way to deduce that.
